# sum in 4 table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i am try to sum quantity in 4 tables and i want the result to be like what in the picture:
example: 
quantity of item1 in initial = 10 + quantity of item1 in buy =10
so the sum of the item in two above tables is 20.
now i want to sum the same item1 in the other to tables..
which is:15 and the result should be: 20-15=5
i tried sum:

```
select productName,
sum(initial.quantity)+sum(buy.quantity) as total1
-
sum(sale.quantity)+sum(free.quantity) as total2
from products
group by productName
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your tables do not necessarily have values for all items in all tables (i.e has initial value, but no sales yet), it would be safer to do it like this:

```
select p.productName, sum(q.iquantity)+sum(q.bquantity) - sum(q.squantity) - sum(q.fquantity) as 'quantity'
from products p
  join (
    select product_id, quantity as iquantity, 0 as bquantity,  0 as squantity, 0 as fquantity
    from initial 
    union
    select product_id, 0, quantity, 0, 0
    from buy
    union
    select product_id, 0, 0, quantity, 0
    from sale
    union
    select product_id, 0, 0, 0, quantity
    from free
  ) as q on q.product_id = p.product_id
group by p.productName
```

Comment: i got right products name but wrong value.. it is near to what i want but still getting the wrong total

Comment: i will vote this until i got the right answer to accept it

Comment: According to the logic given, the ITEM3 should be (4+12)-(12+0) = 4 (not 16). Same goes with ITEM4: (13+13)-(13-0) = 13 (not 26). This is what the query produces.
The UNION just makes the four tables to be seen as one with column for each table's quantity-column. This way it does not matter if there are no values on individual tables as opposed of doing direct joins to each table.

Comment: ok there is a mistake item4 it should be 4 not 16 and for item3 it should be 13 not 26.. i will update

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `GROUP BY` just `JOIN` your tables and use math.

```
SELECT i.productid,
(i.quantity + b.quantity) - (s.quantity + f.quantity) AS quantity
FROM initial i
INNER JOIN buy b ON i."product id" = b."product id"
INNER JOIN sale s ON i."product id" = s."product id"
INNER JOIN free f ON i."product id" = f."product id"
```

Comment: hi! with group by i got wrong result and without group by i got item1 item1 item1 ...... and no sum yet

Answer (score 0):

you need to write as a one column

like (10+10)-(10+5)
if you have multiple time same product than use **GROUP BY** and **SUM** otherwise remove it.

```
 select products.PRODUCT_ID,
    (sum(initial.quantity)+sum(buy.quantity))-(sum(sale.quantity)+sum(free.quantity)) as 
    from products join initial on products.product_id=initial.product_id
    join free on products.product_id=free.product_id
    join buy on products.product_id=buy.product_id
    join sale on products.product_id=sale.product_id
   group by products.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: like (10+10)-(10+5)  yes thats what i want exactly.. but i did not got the right result from your exampl

Comment: @AntiAtlasDev  can you run now ?

Comment: hi! with group by i got wrong result and without group by i got item1 item1 item1 ...... and no sum yet

Comment: @AntiAtlasDev can you check now ?

Comment: select (sum(initial.quantity)+sum(buy.quantity)) from rom initial 
    join buy on products.product_id=buy.product_id where initial.product_id='ITEM1'

Comment: the result should be come correct but something you miss with your original query.

Comment: when i join any table with product table and sum the second table i got the right result in this way: select p.productID, sum(b.quantitty)
from products p 
join buy b on p.productID=b.productID
where p.productID='item1'